# Display video 360 nodejs api createquery not taking params passed

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer, double-click-advertising

I have the following code, trying to create a query using nodejs [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis).

```
let display360 = google.doubleclickbidmanager({
    version: "v1",
    auth: oauth2Client
});

let advertisersParams = {
    "metadata": {
        "dataRange": "LAST_90_DAYS",
        "title": "Advertisers List",
        "sendNotification": false,
    },
    "params": {
        "type": "TYPE_GENERAL",
        "filters":[{
            "type": "FILTER_PARTNER",
            "value": "xxxxxxx"
        }],
        "includeInviteData": false,
        "groupBys": ["FILTER_ADVERTISER"],
        "metrics": ["METRIC_IMPRESSIONS"]
    },
    "schedule": {
        "frequency": "ONE_TIME"
    }
};

display360.queries.createquery(advertisersParams, function(error, response){

    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    }

    if(response){
       console.log(response)
    }
});
```

The `advertisersParams` value is taken directly from the Google API Explorer and it works properly but using the same params on the API call, it fails and reports that `schedule`, `metadata`, and `params` are required, which puzzles me since I've passed them above as `advertisersParams`, am I passing them wrong or this could be a bug of some kind??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved on the GitHub page, turns out the params I am passing need to be wrapped in a requestBody object, check out the answer [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1514#issuecomment-449614296)